# ASP.NET session management for huge object instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

What is the best way to approach to ASP.NET session management, when I keep in mind I have a huge object instance to keep in session, also this should be database managed i.e. the session id is kept in database.

Also the object instance that I keep in session has data table instances within.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/ comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET has few session state providers, one is `SqlSessionStateStore` which stores session state in the SQL server.

You can read more on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478952.aspx).

Another thing is that storing huge objects in a session(especially DataTables) seems like a bad idea. One thing is that you can hit memory issues with date, locks and data going out of sync, another is that retrieving, serializing and deserializing it can be both time and resources consuming.

Comment: plus 1 for your answer. Though I will keep this discussion open to invite more comments.

Comment: I've mentioned exactly this approach - it **requires serialization** of objects, stored in session. And you can end up with much more refactoring simply trying to add/fix serialization for your 'huge objects', than simply rewriting it ;)

Comment: @justmara I believe we added posts simultaneously ;)

Answer (score 0):

'Best way' would be removing huge objects from session storage. Data table instance in session storage is a total '*never use session like this*' example.

ASP.NET session is a InProc collection (by default). It saves in current process memory all the data you place to 'Session' collection. So if apppool flushes - you loose session.

Every single type of 'session provider' you can try to use would require serializing the data placed in session. This means HUGE problems for your data tables.

Comment: I know we should not keep data-table, this is un-managed memory, but this is legacy code and conversion is heavy time consuming. Currently we would think what's best with it.